# How to delete a row dynamically from excel and save using VB.net or C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, excel

I'm reading data from *Excel* and processing the file line by line.

If the process succeeds then I need to delete that row from Excel and save it. If it fails, then continue with the next line and so on.

Initially I used OLEDB to read data from Excel, but by using this I cannot delete rows.

I think we can solve this by using COM component. I'd appreciate your help to solve this issue.

Comment: FYI, the language is named "C#", not "C#.net".

Answer (score 3):

**Using Office Interop/COM on the server (ASP.NET...) is NOT supported by MS** - see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2

To deal with Excel files (*for example delete rows*) in a server-scenario there are several options (free and commercial) out there:

I can recommend [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) and [Flexcel](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp)... didn't try [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) but hear+read lots of good things about it (and it has also a component which can display Excel in ASP.NET etc.).

Free options (though for the newer xlsx format only!) are for example  [OpenXML 2 from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) and [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Hi,There is any way to delete row dynamically using vb.net

Comment: @user490112 yes, there are several ways... just follow the links above... they lead to libraries (some free, some commercial) which can do that...

Comment: Iam using this code .  Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook = New Excel.Workbook Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application") xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("D:\Dilip\NewFile.xls") xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1) Dim str As String = xlSheet.Name Dim rg As Excel.Range = xlSheet.Rows("2:2") rg.Select() rg.Delete() xlBook.Save() xlApp.Quit() System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlBook) System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp)

Comment: @user490112 see the first link in my answer - the code you use is NOT supported by MS for ASP.NET!

Comment: @user490112: do not use that code for ASP.NET or any other server-based application. It is not supported because it was not designed for server applications, and **does not work**. Worse, it may _seem_ to work, then leave you to spend months of effort trying to "fix bugs", when the only fix is to not use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out http://www.officewriter.com/ it works great and supports both Excel binary file format (xls), and the OOXML file format (xlsx). Yahia is correct in saying using Office Interop/COM on the server is NOT supported by Microsoft. In my experience third party tools have greater performance, are easier to work with, and are more flexible.

On a side note OfficeWriter also has Word support, and is not limited to just Excel.